# Which distros or variants of Linux ARE NOT affected by the new CoC?

Tags: distro-recommendation

I don't want my OS to be ruined if code contributors follow through;

> Some have threatened to pull out their blocks of code important to the project to revolt against the change.

https://hub.packtpub.com/linux-programmers-opposed-to-new-code-of-conduct-threaten-to-pull-code-from-project/ 
https://lulz.com/linux-devs-threaten-killswitch-coc-controversy-1252/

So what distros/variants are not affected by the new Code of Conduct? I'm told BSD may not be? and Gentoo? But with them all being based in Linux, won't every variation, including Ubuntu, be affected?

Comment: fyi:  BSD is not Linux, it existed (1979) before Linus Torvalds created what became know Linux (1991), before microsoft started selling DOS (1981) or windows (1985).  BSD is a real form of unix, where as Linux relies on GNU to provide the unix-like features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Linux distributions are affected because Linux is the name of the kernel of the distribution. For a distribution not to be affected, it must not be Linux kernel based.

BSD has its own kernel, it is not Linux kernel based. So it is not affected.

Solaris is another Unix like system that is not Linux based. MacOS, AIX, HP-UX and Minix are also in this category. There are other older Unix distros also that I am surely forgetting.

Ubuntu, Fedora, Suse, Arch, Gentoo and all the other Linux kernel based distributions are certainly affected.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for the clear and informative answers, Now I understand. Would you believe I got called a troll for asking this elsewhere? and said accusers thought that their Linux based operating systems would not be affected.